# Ran Java code in netbeans without any problems. Though the Table does not appear in Mysql Workbench

Tags: java, mysql

Please start by knowing I am a total beginner. The code that will be posted below is from "YouTube".

The code is to establish a connection to Mysql workbench database "mysql".
Purpose is to create a table with column names.
The project runs fine. Well! No visible hick-ups. The output window in Netbeans reads:
 run:
 Connected
 Function complete.
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Can't negotiate MySQL Workbench documentation to possible reasons for not listed the Table. But still looking.

I replaced part of the "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS..." with "CREATE TABLE..."

The output window in Netbeans then reads:
 run:
 Connected
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'actors' 
 already exists
 Function complete.
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

```
package homemovies;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;


    public class HomeMovies {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws 
    Exception { creatTable(); }

    public static void creatTable() throws Exception{
     try{
       Connection con = getConnection();
       PreparedStatement create = 
       con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
           Actors(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
                 + "Fname varchar(255), Lname 
                 varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY(id))");
                 create.executeUpdate();
       }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
            finally{System.out.println("Function 
            complete.");}
        }
    public static Connection getConnection() throws 
    Exception{
     try{
      String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
      String username = "username here";
      String password = "password here";
      Class.forName(driver);

    Connection conn = 

       DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
       System.out.println("Connected");
       return conn;
       }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

    return null;
        }
    }
```

Expect the table "Actors" to be listed in Tables section of MySQL Workbench.
I tried additional things like stopping the server, closing MySQL Workbench application; Restarting the application and the server. The Table "Actors" still continues not to show up where it should.

Please help.
Appreciate your time.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IF NOT EXISTS prevents error from occuring. You can check the manual here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

If you try to run the query multiple times without IF NOT EXISTS in MySQL workbench, you would get a similar error.

Comment: I am writing code in Java Netbeans to CREATE a table, then update the mysql workbench database. Mysql workbench database does not list the table created in Java Netbeans. Why/How do I get Mysql workbench to list the table? Please

Comment: probably it would work if you add `con.commit();` after `create.executeUpdate();`

Comment: Thank you, but Java Netbeans outputs Table 'actors' already exists. I wonder where Java Netbeans is looking. You know, to make such a statement that the table exist?